# Jquery UI Not Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jquery draggable ui , but it seems like the ui is not well imported

I'd run this test :

```
if(jQuery.ui){
    alert("loaded");
        }
    else
    {
        alert("not loaded");
    }
```

And got an "not loaded" alert....

Here are the first code lines of the file i'm writing :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <?php
    $searchQuery = $_POST['searchQuery'];
    ?>

    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea what might went wrong ?

*I'm already using another jQuery functions which work just fine , so the jquery package is imported for sure , I gurss the problem is the ui import did not success.

Comment: Your code seems correct. Can you check in your browser's dev tools what is the return status of jQuery UI request?

Comment: check javascript console for errors

Comment: Why are you loading such an old version of jQuery?  There may be a clash between your newer jQueryUI library and the older main library.

Comment: may be noscript blocks ajax.googleapis.com ?

Comment: jQuery UI page says: The current versions are: jQuery UI 1.8.22: Works with jQuery 1.3.2+ jQuery UI 1.7.2: Works with jQuery 1.3.2+ - so that should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (jQuery.ui || jQuery.ui != "undefined") {
    alert("loaded")
}
```

You can always just try to load a random UI item (pulled from jQuery ui website)
HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
```

If the HTML block doesn't show up as an accordion element, then it isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  $( function() { $("#accordion").accordion();} );
```